# Powerbi Calendar slider not filtering Measure / visual correct

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have issues with filtering visuals by a Date Table Slicer. Some visuals (date on x-axis) pick up a filtered date, others do not. To me this seems to occur whenver I have a Measure with date argument specified, but I was not able to find the reason.

I have two tables with Dates:

- Calendar -> Date  starting 2011
- Performance-> DATE starting 2018

Some thoughts:

- Both dates have same datatype
- I am not sure which date axis I need to use in visuals ( Calendar or Performance table)
- i am not sure which date I need to reference in measures ( Calendar or Performance table)

The measure Formula I use:

```
Indexed PRICE = 
VAR Date_index =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Performance'[DATE] ); ALLSELECTED ( Performance ) )
RETURN
    (( SUM ( Performance[PRICE_EUR] )  )
        / (
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( Performance[PRICE_EUR] ); Performance[DATE] = Date_index )
        )
        -1)
```

In the visual Filter for Calendar[Date] I selected 2018 as startdate (as this is the minimum date of Performance[DATE].

However, the visual is showing the whole available Dates of Calendar[Dates] which is back until 2011).Any idea what I need to change?

Here is a link to a comparison:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAqc7.jpg

Comment: It should be fine if there is a relationship on Calendar[date] = Performance[date]. Can you post a screen please?

Comment: Thanks Prakash, unforunatley I am not able yet to post pictures in my posts. But the tables are linked https://imgur.com/3wDQQ55